# CKEditor codesnippet plugin is not working with ckeditor gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using [ckeditor](https://rubygems.org/gems/ckeditor) gem in my Rails application. I am trying to add [codesnippet](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet) plugin to my CKEditor.

I have downloaded the zip file and extracted it to `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins` and added this:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
```

to `config.js` file.

But I am getting this error:

```
File not found: /assets/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js?t=G6DE

Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "widget" was not found at "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js?t=G6DE".
 /assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.self.js?body=1:236
```

Answer (score 0):

Its stated on the [download page](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codesnippet) that there are dependencies which include
[Widget](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget) & [Dialog](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialog) plugins.
I suppose you already have [Dialog](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialog). You need to download the [Widget](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget) plugin, include it in your plugins filder and add it to your extraplugins settings. i.e

```js
config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet,widget';
```

This should solve it.
**Note**: The widet plugin also has 3 dependencies. [Line Utilities](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lineutils),    [Clipboard](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/clipboard) and [Widget Selection](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widgetselection). Ensure you have included these plugins in your plugins folder and  added them in the extraplugins config.
 
And all will be fine ;)